# Binwalk not extracting files from binary

Tags: reverse-engineering

I am using binwalk, its finding files but nothing is extracted afterwards
I have done this before and have not had issues. Are these not files?

```
babak@G750JHA ~/Desktop $ binwalk -Me ./Cottonelle.bin

Scan Time:     2016-06-18 23:19:58
Target File:   /home/ubuntu/babak/Desktop/Cottonelle.bin
MD5 Checksum:  f330370ed549c30bb301b42e7363ce32
Signatures:    345

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16560         0x40B0          PEM RSA private key
18608         0x48B0          PEM certificate
20484         0x5004          PEM certificate
32944         0x80B0          PEM RSA private key
34992         0x88B0          PEM certificate
36868         0x9004          PEM certificate
301529        0x499D9         Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 177
414737        0x65411         Boot section Start 0x42423242 End 0x0
414741        0x65415         Boot section Start 0x0 End 0x0
414911        0x654BF         Boot section Start 0x3C42 End 0x0
414915        0x654C3         Boot section Start 0x0 End 0x0
415370        0x6568A         Boot section Start 0x14 End 0x30000
518776        0x7EA78         PEM RSA private key
520488        0x7F128         PEM certificate
521984        0x7F700         PEM certificate
531224        0x81B18         HTML document header
532867        0x82183         HTML document footer
532876        0x8218C         HTML document header
533428        0x823B4         HTML document footer
533440        0x823C0         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
549524        0x86294         SHA256 hash constants, little endian
550196        0x86534         PEM RSA private key
550592        0x866C0         PEM certificate
788672        0xC08C0         Copyright string: "Copyright (c) 1996-2011 Express Logic Inc. * NetX Cortex-M3/GNU Version G5.4.5.0 SN: 23451-108-0509 *"
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use `binwalk --dd=".*" file_name`.
Above command instructs Binwalk to extract any file type.

It seems Binwalk with `-e` just extract files with known or complete header.

Comment: Elaborating a bit, the file format's definition must include a [`{size}`](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/wiki/Signature-File-Format) element, otherwise binwalk doesn't know how much data to extract.

Answer (score 3):

The firmware you have is from Amazon Dash. I know this from the MD5 hash. Many people have done a great job at reversing it. Google around and also check this out: https://hackaday.io/project/5832-exploring-amazon-dash-button.

Answer (score -5):

It seems that the binary file is encrypted. Do reverse engineering to find the encryption algorithm. Then only you can do the decryption. You need to decrypt the firmware before running it through binwalk.